# How to prove the resonate theorem using Gelfand Lemma.

Tags: functional-analysis, bilinear-operator

Here is the **Gelfand lemma**:Suppose $X$ is a Banach space, $p:X\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies :

1. $p(x)\ge 0$;
2. $p(\lambda x)=\lambda p(x),\quad \forall \lambda>0$;
3. $p(x_1+x_2)\le p(x_1)+p(x_2)$;
4. $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}p(x_n)\ge p(x)$ where $x_n\to x$.

Then there exists $M>0$ such that $p(x)\le M||x||$.

I have proved it and try to use it to prove the **uniform boundness principle**:

Let $X,Y$
be Banach spaces and  $\{A_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ be a family of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. If $\{A_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ is pointwise bounded on X, then $\{A_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ is uniformly bounded, i.e., $\sup∥T_λ∥<\infty$.

I considered to show that $\sup\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda}||A_\lambda x||$ is the $p(x)$ in Gelfand Lemma but I failed.

Comment: What is the resonate theorem?

Comment: @copper.hat In this context, the resonate theorem would be referring to the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: @DeanMiller Thanks. A bit off topic, but does the Gelfand lemma go by another name? I have never heard of it.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not sure. I've never seen this result before and haven't heard of this lemma either.

Comment: @DeanMiller Thanks anyways!

Comment: @copper.hat No problem! If this helps, it appears that you can show that a lower semicontinuous function on a Banach space is bounded on some open subset. Then I would suspect that you can use that the function is subadditive to deduce the result of the Gelfand lemma. This doesn't help if you are looking for a name of the result, but it may be useful if you are looking for a proof.

Comment: @DeanMiller Thanks! It seems like a result I should know. I am looking for a proof based on convex analysis ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Your initial attempt at defining $p: X \to \mathbb{R}$ by $p(x) := \sup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \| A_{\lambda} (x) \|$ is indeed a good approach. The most challenging part is to show that the fourth result holds.

To show this, let $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$ with limit $x$. Let $\lambda \in \Lambda$. By the continuity of $A_{\lambda}$ and the norm, it follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \| A_{\lambda}(x_{n}) \| = \|A_{\lambda}(x)\|$. In particular, $\|A_{\lambda}(x)\| \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \|A_{\lambda}(x_{n})\|$. As a direct result of this,

$$ \| A_{\lambda}(x) \| \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \|A_{\lambda}(x_{n})\| \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \left( \sup_{\gamma \in \Lambda} \|A_{\gamma}(x_{n}) \| \right) = \liminf_{n \to \infty}p(x_{n}).$$

As this holds for all $\lambda \in \Lambda$, $\liminf_{n \to \infty}p(x_{n})$ is an upper bound for $\{\|A_{\lambda}(x)\| : \lambda \in \Lambda \}$. But as $p(x) = \sup \{\|A_{\lambda}(x)\| : \lambda \in \Lambda \}$, it follows that $p(x) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty}p(x_{n})$.

The other three parts should be straightforward to verify from the definitions.

Comment: Many Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @yxLee No problem! You can accept the answer if it helped answer your question.